# Nativescript Android open Waze link from webview

Tags: android, nativescript, nativescript-vue, waze

Whenever I click a Waze link on an Android device that is loaded in a webview from my app, I get to a waze page with suggestion to download Waze (even though the Waze app is installed).

On iOS, I get directly to Waze.

Waze link looks like this: `https://www.waze.com/ul?q=address-here&navigate=yes`

Is there anyway I can make Android device go straight to Waze app from the webview on Android?

Comment: You may listen to `loadStarted` or `loadFinished` event, if the URL is waze, you may use [openUrl](https://docs.nativescript.org/core-concepts/utils#openurl-function), if Waze handles the url then that will open the app.

Comment: @Manoj Great idea! The only thing I had to do is stop the actual waze page from loading in the app by using `webView.stopLoading()` but this lead to previous url to stop working.

Any ideas how I could keep the url at the same state when clicking the url without reloading the page after my custom URL open?